# Go IDE With GUI Design Support

Tags: ide, go, gui-designer

I was taking a look on Go language, but I want to know if there is any IDE developed only for it, but that have a GUI design feature, as Visual Studio and Netbeans.

Comment: as neat as go it self: http://code.google.com/p/golangide/wiki/Screen

Comment: latest version GoLangIde/liteide doesn't actually work for me at all, on ubuntu, as of March 2012. Oh well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also find an Eclipse plugin here: http://code.google.com/p/goclipse/

However, at the moment of writing this is still at an early development stage.

Answer (score 32):

Go isn't really designed for GUIs - it's precisely designed to meet the kind of needs that Google has.

I dare say it's entirely possible to develop GUI frameworks with/in it, but it's not the team's priority as far as I'm aware.

Comment: That the core Go with its standard library, which is kept relatively small deliberately, does not provide GUI functionality does not mean that there may be competent, full-fledged GUI libraries by third parties. Furthermore, IMO the focus of the core Go team doesn’t really say much on available IDEs, potentially with WYSIWYG-GUI-Designers. – While C(++) does not provide GUI functionality in their main library, several GUI frameworks and IDEs came to be. As the question was not specifically on an official GUI or IDE, this answer is IMO from a bit narrow of a view, and not really on the point.

Comment: @Kissaki: Back two years ago, when Go was pretty new, I think it was entirely reasonable. It's not like 3rd parties had had much time to develop an IDE or a good, idiomatic GUI library. It's more feasible that it could have happened by now, although I'm not personally aware of any GUI libraries targeted at Go.

Comment: @JonSkeet: From the [Go Projects](http://godashboard.appspot.com/project) I've found [walk](https://github.com/lxn/walk) (Windows-only, also understands Qt Designer ui files) and [go.uik](https://github.com/skelterjohn/go.uik) (cross-platform, at early development stages).

Comment: There are now [QML bindings for Go](https://github.com/go-qml/qml).

Answer (score 6):

lite ide is little, cross platform and open source.you can try it.
http://code.google.com/p/golangide/

Answer (score 5):

For my Go programming I use the [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com/go.html) editor. It's definitely **NOT** a Go GUI IDE but at least for me the gocode auto complete feature is great.

Comment: +1 The gocode auto complete feature is nice.

Comment: The integrated gdb debugger could be a little prettier but at least it does work.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Notepad++ for now, there is a language file for it here:
http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/notepad-plus-plus/

Comment: Back when I checked them out, when Go 1.0 was already released, they were outdated. After I updated them for myself, I published them. https://github.com/Kissaki/Notepadpp-UDLs/tree/master/go

Answer (score 2):

I've been using gedit with C syntax highlighting selected and bash shell for compiling and testing. I keep the Linux version of Google Chrome browser running local copy of Go documentation. Under Xubuntu window manager I can flip the browser window up and down out of the title bar for whenever I need to look at package APIs.

Go compiles and links very fast - I'm just as productive with this set of tools as I've ever been using Java and C# IDEs. Kind of refreshing to write software with just "stone knives and bear skins".

Answer (score 2):

Most of the main Go developers use [Acme](http://acme.cat-v.org) A programming environment by Rob Pike, it is very different from a traditional IDE, but if you are open-minded and get over the first shock, it can be extremely pleasant to use.

Comment: No syntax highlighting?  This is automatic fail in 2012.

Comment: Why is syntax highlighting important?

Comment: Although this is interesting on the IDE part, the question was actually on GUI-editing and -designing in an IDE. As far as I can see, nothing of that is provided by Acme. Right?

Comment: Syntax highlighting is (subjectively) very helpful at (quickly) reading code and grasping its logic. You can easier scan the code for its different aspects and contents. Rather then relying on words alone (which you first have to read), syntax highlighting adds additional formatting and/or coloring hints for the eye and brain.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cloud-IDE.com online editor and online deploy - All FREE !!

Comment: Got any info on that? I couldn't find any Go support

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best options for developing Go are TextWrangler, Vim, or BBedit.